Use SDK to mimic the BitMovin Stream dashboard upload feature
Using the BitMovin Streams service, I want to:

Upload a video file
Get the stream Id
Use the HTML5 player

No transformation or muxing.
The Bitmovin dashboard offers this feature out of the box: select a file -> it gets uploaded -> no setup to be done -> the stream is ready.
The steps are straight forward:


I'm looking for a way to do exactly that (and nothing more) using the SDK (C#, but any documentation would do).
Uploading works thanks to their example. I currently tried some examples from the documentation but it seems very convoluted while the dashboard flow shows a very easy process.
The (simplified) code below uploads successfully, creates encoding and stream, but in the end: I have no manifest, no stream-id.
    var fileInput = await _bitmovinApi.Encoding.Inputs.DirectFileUpload.CreateAsync(new());
    var fileContent = new StreamContent(fileStream);
    var fileUploadContent = new MultipartFormDataContent { { fileContent, "file", filename } };
    var fileUploadResponse = await _httpClient.PutAsync(fileInput.UploadUrl, fileUploadContent, args.CancellationToken);
    if (!fileUploadResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        throw await fileUploadResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var codecConfig = await _bitmovinApi.Encoding.Configurations.Video.H264.CreateAsync(new()
    {
        DynamicRangeFormat = H264DynamicRangeFormat.SDR
    });

    var encoding = await _bitmovinApi.Encoding.Encodings.CreateAsync(new() 
    { 
        Name = filename 
    });

    var stream = await _bitmovinApi.Encoding.Encodings.Streams.CreateAsync(encoding.Id, new()
    {
        InputStreams = [new()
        {
            InputId = fileInput.Id,
            InputPath = fileInput.UploadUrl,
        }], 
        CodecConfigId = codecConfig.Id
    });

Is there a easier way to create a stream programmatically?
Am I looking at the wrong service/provider to do such a simple scenario?

I believe you are using the wrong API here.
The workflow you refer to is the Streams product, our all-in-one API that enables this seamless workflow and it is a different API from the main Encoding API that you're referencing in the post.
What you are looking for is described in our documentation here: https://developer.bitmovin.com/streams/docs/use-cdn-file-upload-with-streams
As you can see the main endpoint to create a stream and retrieve a streamId is the POST call to https://api.bitmovin.com/v1/streams/video (doc)
The create streams call requires a file to be already uploaded to the internet and that's where the Direct File Upload API comes in which you're already correctly using.
Hope this helps.

Thanks for your answer: indeed I confused Stream and Encoding features. So I guess, the question remains: is there a clean way to build/get the URL for the manifests? I found some ways to build it manually (based on output choices, ...) but it seems convoluted. I was wondering if there were an API to just get the Manifest full url all tailored and built without messing around with string construction?
